# Can't update code in python package even after building and running twine with different versions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, package, python-packaging

I have a python package that has a .py file called `cli.py`. In the pacakge I keep getting a `NameError: name 'op' is not defined` because a variable was not defined. I updated the `cli.py` file but I can't seem to be able to see that in my python package.

The code in the `cli.py` file in my package is:

```
def get_google_header(url, file_path, file_name, h_area):
    s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=op)
    agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
    print(agent)
    driver.maximize_window()

    for files in os.listdir(file_path):
        if files.endswith(file_name):
            csv_name = file_path + files
            print(csv_name)
```

But in my local file I have the code as:

```
def get_google_header(url, file_path, file_name, h_area):
    op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # add user Agent
    # op.add_argument
    # ("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"
    # +"AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
    # +"Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36")
    # set chromedriver.exe path
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe",
    # options=op)
    op.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    op.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    op.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    op.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    op.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, chrome_options=op)
    agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
    print(agent)
    driver.maximize_window()

    for files in os.listdir(file_path):
        if files.endswith(file_name):
            csv_name = file_path + files
            print(csv_name)
```

I have all the other package imported correctly. It's just that this latest code doesn't seem to be updated even if I run `python3 -m build` > `python3 -m twine upload --verbose --repository testpypi dist/*`

would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: that's because there's no `op` variable defined in `get_google_header` function in cli.py